# Add an 'x' between product attributes, not adding an 'x' after the last attribute

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

im trying to add an x in between attributes when there are multiple attributes , here's my code:

```
    $meta_data = $item->get_formatted_meta_data( '' );

     if ( $meta_data ) {


    foreach ( $meta_data as $meta_id => $meta ) {
    if ( in_array( $meta->key, $hidden_order_itemmeta, true ) ) {
    continue;
    }
    $html .= wp_kses_post( force_balance_tags( $meta->display_value ) ) ;
    }

    }
    break;
```

Can i just change it to :

```
    $html .= return implode( ' x ', wp_kses_post( force_balance_tags( $meta->display_value ) ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure if I understand you correctly, but maybe this example and the usage of PHP's [next() function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.next.php) could help you.

It loops through an array and prints X until the very last array element:

```
<?php
    /** Define the array */
    $fruits = [
        "Apple",
        "Banana",
        "Orange",
        "Kiwi",
        "Cherry"
    ];
    
    /** Start loop */
    foreach ($fruits as $fruit) {
        
        /** Print the fruit and "X" if the array is not at the end */
        if(next($fruits)) {
            echo "$fruit X ";
        }
        else {
            /** Only print the fruit if the array has ended */
            echo $fruit;
        }
    }
```

The output:

```
Apple X Banana X Orange X Kiwi X Cherry
```

I don't have WP installed at the moment, but I hope it helps nonetheless.